# Power supply troubles/ want to buy another one

Tags: power-supply, reboot

The thing is my pc restarts by itself (mostly one-time per run(sometimes twice)). The most common situation for it to restart is when I play games(pretty much every game). Sometimes it restarts at the very beggining I turn it on. The restart process starts with the system and sound freeze(like it stacks at one sound and keeps repeating it till the computer restarts or I restart it manually.

I switched from box cooler to DeepCool GAMMAXX 200T, clean it up from dust but it doesn't help much. I suppose the bottleneck is the power supply, hence I want to change it. Please advise either your idea of what the problem might be or a good power supply to buy instead of the old one.

Computer specs:
CPU - Intel Core i5-7400
RAM - 16GB(ddr4, elite 2x8GB, 2400Hz)
GPU - NVIDIA 1050ti
Motherboard - Asus Prime B250M-A
cooler - DeepCool GAMMAXX 200T + a small fan Dark Force 9cm 
Power supply - aero cool VX series 700w

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a lack of power is causing the reboots, since a 700w power supply should be more than enough, even if you have several HDDs connected.
My guess is that the system reboots because of overheating. Another reason might be that the power unit is not providing a stable output.
I recommend to use LibreHardwareMonitor and run a few tests, like AIDA64 or Prime95, to check what the actual temperatures are before the reboot.

Comment: ok, I see. Thanks! And where may I turn on a temperature reading process to store results(in AIDA64)? So i can get them after the restart.

Comment: You need to use LibreHardwareMonitor for that. See Options > Log Sensors

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other things plugged into the area circuit where the PC is ? Sometimes it is not getting enough power to supply the unit. My friend had her's plugged into a socket shared with her fishtank. Bad news, blew a few power supplies. Finally she moved the PC and all is well. Have you tried running it without the cover? Make sure all the fans are working. Sometimes also, you may need to reseat items such as the memory and cables to the harrdisks. Good luck